# Algo estoy haciendo mal en Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-8

casi me rompo la cabeza con un problema que me ocurre con un query SQL en Laravel 8. Estoy en el controlador recibiendo dos variables por la url, solo utilizo una por los momentos, el controlador recibe bien el contenido de la variable porque le doy un **return** y me lo imprime en la vista. A continuación coloco el código:

public function store(Request $request, $rep, $ide)
{

```
    //return $ide; Aquí imprime bien el contenido de la variable, que es un id

    $repre = Represtudiantes::select('*')->where('ide', $ide)->get();//Aquí hago el query
    
    if (empty($repre)) { //Aquí hago una simple comprobación con un if
        echo 'Hola estoy Vacío';
    }else{
        echo 'Hola estoy Llenito';
    }
}
```

Se supone que cuando la variable **$ide** se busca en la BD y se encuentra, se envía el contenido del registro a la variable **$repre** y se debe imprimir la cadena **"Hola estoy Llenito"** porque la variable **$repre** no está vacía y si por el contrario, el **$ide** no está en la BD no devuelve nada a $repre, por lo que en el if se debe ejecutar la cadena **"Hola estoy Vacío"**, pues bien, he aquí el problema, porque en el segundo caso, cuando la variable **$ide** no está en la BD también devuelve la cadena **"Hola estoy Llenito**".

He probado mil cosas y no sé por qué hace esto, debería imprimirse el **"Hola estoy Vacío"** en el caso que no se encuentre el **$ide** en la BD pero no es así. **¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

P.D.: Este es el modelo:

class Represtudiantes extends Model
{

```
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'ide',
    'idr'
];
```

}

Lo estoy llamando bien desde el controlador.

Disculpen lo largo, gracias.

Comment: Porque lo que te devuelve la consulta es un collection de Laravel, a pesar de que tenga 0 registros, es decir, no está vacía esa variable, te retorna algo, en este caso un collection. Los collection debes evaluarlos con los [métodos propios de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods)

Comment: @BetaM Muchas gracias, con el "first" y el "is_null" funciona bien, es que dependiendo de ese if evalúo si guardo el $ide en la BD o si ya está no debo guardarlo, muchas gracias...

Comment: @BetaM ok gracias por tu ayuda!